# Um exercicio em python porém não consegui entender a lógica

Tags: python

***Se poderem me ajudar a principalmente entender serei grato***

5. As funções abaixo constituem parte de uma biblioteca editada em um arquivo, denominado f_matriz.py e devidamente instalada com caminho atribuído à lista no arquivo sys.py.

```
#
# >>> A=leia_matriz(n_l,n_c) <<<
# leia_matriz(n_l,n_c) .... Realiza a leitura de uma matriz com números inteiros
# n_l ............................... número de linhas da matriz
# n_c............................... número de colunas da matriz
#
def leia_matriz(n_l,n_c):
    matriz=[]
    for i in range(0,n_l):
        matriz_c=[]
        for j in range(0,n_c):
            print(" >>> Digite o elemento [",i+1,"][",j+1,"] da Matriz",end="")
            elemento_matriz=int(input(" ==> "))
            matriz_c.append(elemento_matriz)
        matriz.append(matriz_c)
    return matriz

#
# >>>escreva_matriz(matriz)
# escreva_matriz(matriz) .........Apresenta a matriz
#
def escreva_matriz(matriz):
    n_l=len(matriz)
    n_c=len(matriz[0])
    for i in range(0,n_l):
        for j in range(0,n_c):
            print("\t\t",matriz[i][j],end="")
        print("")
    return

#
# >>>soma_matriz(matriz1,matriz2)
# atribui a uma matriz a soma da matriz1 com a matriz2
#
def soma_matriz(matriz1,matriz2):
    nl_matriz1=len(matriz1)
    nl_matriz2=len(matriz2)
    if nl_matriz1 != nl_matriz2:
        return "Matrizes incompatíveis - número de linhas diferentes )-: "
    nc_matriz1=len(matriz1[0])
    nc_matriz2=len(matriz2[0])
    if nc_matriz1 != nc_matriz2:
        return "Matrizes incompatíveis - número de colunas diferentes )-: "
    matriz_soma=[]
    linha_matriz=[]
    for i in range(0,nl_matriz1):
        for j in range(0,nc_matriz1):
            linha_matriz.append(0)
        matriz_soma.append(linha_matriz)
        linha_matriz=[]
    for i in range(0,nl_matriz1):
        for j in range(0,nc_matriz1):
            matriz_soma[i][j]=matriz1[i][j]+matriz2[i][j]
    return matriz_  ssoma
```

Considere a elaboração de um programa editado na linguagem Python que faz uso desta biblioteca para:Leitura, Soma de duas matrizes, e Exibição do resultado final desta soma. Assinale a alternativa em que o programa corresponde corretamente a estas operações.

a)

```
importf_matriz
A=leia_matriz(3,5)
B=leia_matriz(5,3)
soma_matriz(A,B)
C=escreva_matriz(linhas,colunas)
```

b)

```
importf_matriz
A=f_matriz.leia_matriz(4,3)
B=f_matriz.leia_matriz(4,3)
C=f_matriz.soma_matriz(A,B)
f_matriz.escreva_matriz(C)
```

c)

```
A=leia_matriz(3,2)
B=leia_matriz(2,3)
soma_matriz(A,B)
C=escreva_matriz(linhas,colunas)
```

d)

```
importf_matriz
    A=leia_matriz(linhas,colunas)
B=leia_matriz(linhas,colunas)
soma_matriz(A,B)
C=escreva_matriz(linhas,colunas)
```

e)

```
importf_matriz
A=leia_matriz(linhas,colunas)
B=leia_matriz(linhas,colunas)
soma_matriz(A,B)
C=escreva_matriz(linhas,colunas)
```

Justifique sua resposta !

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Answer (score 0):

No python você pode usar os arquivos `.py` de duas maneiras. Ou você executa eles (o arquivo vai ser um "script"), ou você importa funções, classes, etc., desse arquivo (o arquivo vai ser um módulo).

No caso desse arquivo `f_matriz.py` ele define algumas funções que você quer usar e para isso você deve importar primeiro.

Se um módulo se chama `m.py` e define as funções `func1`, `func2` e `func3` você pode importar o módulo todo usando `import m`, pode importar funções específicas usando `from m import func1, func3`, por exemplo. Também é possível importar tudo do módulo com `from m import *`, mas não é muito aconselhável.

Caso importe o **módulo inteiro** na hora de usar uma função é necessário fazer algo como `m.func1(argumentos)`. Nos outros dois casos onde você importa **algo dentro do módulo** e não o **módulo inteiro** você chama a função sem o nome do módulo antes. Ou seja, apenas `func1(argumentos)`.

Isso é suficiente para você entender qual a opção certa e o motivo.

---

Um detalhe final é que ontem tem `importf_matriz` deveria ser `import f_matriz` (com um espaço entre `import` e o nome do módulo).